# Where is the php.ini file in php 7.1?

Tags: php

I download VC14 x64 Non Thread Safe (2017-Jan-18 21:06:20) on http://windows.php.net/download

Then I extract it

Look at the result :

[image]

Seems no php.ini file

Where I found it?

Comment: In the Advanced settings section of the View tab, check "Show hidden files, folder, or drives" and uncheck "Hide protected operating system files", Windows is made to hide them by default - this could be the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just copy `php.ini-development` or `php.ini-production` as new file named `php.ini`. Edit the options and start using it.

Answer (score 0):

For development server rename `php.ini-development` as `php.ini` also for production server `php.ini-production` as `php.ini`